# Conditional Formatting with Lookup first

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, conditional-formatting

Can anyone help me with a formal to perform the following:

1. Conditional Formatting of Table1[@Counter]

**Formula for formatting:**

1. Separate from Table1[@Sex] M vs F.
2. If "M", format only the highest value in Table1[@Counter] where range = "M" (Range is Sorted, but will be resized often, so outcome must be dynamic)
3. If "F", format only the highest value in Table1[@Counter] where range = "F" (Range is Sorted, but will be resized often, so outcome must be dynamic)
4. Redo steps 1-3, but highlight only cell with 2nd highest value accordingly
5. Redo step 4, with 3rd highest value.

What I've tried for steps 1 - 3:
`=IF(TABLE1[@SEX] = "M"; LARGE(OFFSET(ADDRESS(MATCH("M"; TABLE1[@SEX]; 0); 1); 0; 1; COUNTIF(TABLE1[@SEX]; "M")); 1); NA)`

Table1:

`+------------+-----------+---------------+
 | Name (Str) | Sex (Str) | Counter (Int) |
 +------------+-----------+---------------+`

Comment: How is the data sorted? Does it go M-> High->low then Fo-> High->low? Or High->low, with F/M mixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume data is sorted so that all M's are first, going from Highest to Lowest. Then all F's are next, going from Highest to Lowest. This assumption will allow us to simply look for the position of a particular row. ie: find the first row that contains "M" - that row is the highest; the row below that is 2nd highest; the row below that is 3rd highest. Then repeat for the first row that contains "M". Would work as follows, for the three "M" rules ("F" would be identical, with just the "M" switched with "F".

I have assumed that the M/F id is simply in column A - no table identification will be needed.

**Rule 1 - highest "M":**

```
=ROW()=MATCH("M",$A:$A,0)
```

**Rule 2 - 2nd highest "M"**

```
=ROW()=MATCH("M",$A:$A,0)+1
```

**Rule 3 - 3rd highest "M"**

```
=ROW()=MATCH("M",$A:$A,0)+2
```